# Changing the fieldtype of Content in Silverstripe's SiteTree

Tags: silverstripe

Is it possible to change the field type for `Content` in the db from an extension?

It seems I can't override it like so:

```
class ParsedownExtension extends DataExtension {

    private static $db = array(
        'Content' => 'ParsedownField'
    );
}
```

My field type & extension does work because it works fine with a fieldname different to `Content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change a field type by setting it in your `_config.php` file.

**mysite/_config.php**

```php
$fields = Config::inst()->get('SiteTree', 'db', Config::UNINHERITED); 
$fields['Content'] = 'ParsedownField'; 
Config::inst()->update('SiteTree', 'db', $fields);
```

This answer was found a question on the Silverstripe Forum: 
http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/23967